# Dynamically added FormItem doesn't show error text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I am dynamically creating a form on runtime of my application. The content of my form item (lets call it MyFormItemContent) looks like this (simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:BorderContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                   width="100%" borderAlpha="0.0">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <utils:DataItemValidator dataItem="{referenceToDataItem}"
                                 source="{this}"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:HGroup width="100%">
        <s:TextInput width="100%" text="@{bindingToText}"/>
        <s:CheckBox width="14" selected="{refToBoolean}"/>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

and the the code for the the validator we are using. It works fine other parts of the application and debuging shows that a message exists but is not shown.

```
/**
 * This class effectively does *not* validate the given 'value', but just returns
 * his 'dataItem's attached messages.
 */
public class DataItemValidator extends Validator {

    private var _dataItem:StatefulDataItem;

    public function get dataItem():StatefulDataItem {
        return _dataItem;
    }

    public function set dataItem(dataItem:StatefulDataItem):void {
        _dataItem = dataItem;
        ChangeWatcher.watch(_dataItem, "messages", function():void {
            validate();
        }, false);

        validate();
    }

    override protected function doValidation(value:Object):Array {
        if (!isInitialized()) return [];

        // Clear results Array.
        var results:Array = [];
        // If dataItem has error indicator append all messages to result array.
        if (dataItem && dataItem.messages) {
            for each (var message:ResultMessage in dataItem.messages) {
                results.push(new ValidationResult(message.isErroneous(), null, "", message.text));
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    public function isErroneous():Boolean {
        if (!dataItem) return false;
        return dataItem.isErroneous();
    }

    private function isInitialized():Boolean {
        return (dataItem != null);
    }
}
```

The code that declares the form looks like this:

```
<s:Form id="myForm" width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:layout>
        <s:FormLayout gap="-7" paddingBottom="2" paddingLeft="2" paddingRight="2"
                      paddingTop="2"/>
    </s:layout>
</s:Form>
```

And finally, the item is added to the form like this:

```
var formItem:FormItem = new FormItem();
formItem.label = "some text";
formItem.addElement(new MyFormItemContent());
myForm.addElement(formItem);
```

If the validation of MyValidator has errors a red frame apears around the BorderContainer as intended. But unfortunatly the error text that should apear right to the form item doesn't. I'm thinkin it's a layout problem because I define the validator inside the form item content before adding it to the form. I've already debugged this and read documentations a lot.

I thought it would help to know how a FormItem is added to a Form if you declare it in mxml but I couldn't find information on that either.

Comment: where is your validator class ?

Comment: I thought posting the validator would be to much. If you want to verifiy if the validator works: it does! We are using the same one in other UI components and if I debug I can see that a message exists. I can post it anyways if you still want to see it.

Comment: i would like to see that bcoz normal validator its working fine

Comment: I'm interested in your code for that working example because I wasn't able to get it to work with a normal validator either. I'm posting my validator in a minute...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" creationComplete="application2_creationCompleteHandler(event)" xmlns:local="*">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.charts.series.ColumnSeries;
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.containers.FormItem;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;



            protected function application2_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for(var i:int = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    var formItem:FormItem = new FormItem();
                    formItem.label = "some text";
                    formItem.addElement(new MyFormItemContent());
                    myForm.addElement(formItem);
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <s:Form id="myForm" width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:layout>
            <s:FormLayout gap="-7" paddingBottom="2" paddingLeft="2" paddingRight="2"
                          paddingTop="2"/>
        </s:layout>
    </s:Form>


</s:Application>
```

form item mxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:BorderContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                   width="100%" borderAlpha="0.0" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" creationComplete="bordercontainer1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.events.ValidationResultEvent;

            [Bindable]
            private var bindingToText:String;

            [Bindable]
            private var refToBoolean:Boolean;

            protected function bordercontainer1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            protected function txt_focusOutHandler(event:FocusEvent):void
            {
                var obj:ValidationResultEvent = validator.validate(txt.text);
                error.visible = !(obj.type == "valid");
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <mx:PhoneNumberValidator id="validator"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:HGroup width="100%">
        <s:TextInput id="txt" width="100%" text="@{bindingToText}" focusOut="txt_focusOutHandler(event)"/>
        <s:CheckBox width="14" selected="{refToBoolean}"/>
        <s:Label id="error" visible="false" backgroundColor="red" text="This Field Required"/>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

I am posting this code for your interest.

Comment: Now tell me what kinda validation you want to do on this text field ?

Comment: Interesting. If I build it like this I still can't see the error message. Only the TextInput gets the red frame. The code I've posted here is simplified so the error must be somewhere in the lines I left out. This gives me a hint where to look. Unfortunately the whole code is a little bit more complex. I think it would be to much to post here.

Comment: okay when you wanna see the error msg, when the user moved to the other form item or on mouse over of the item ?

Comment: I our other forms the FormItem gets resized and the error message apears to the right. This should be default behaviour of FormItem. Fyi: if I set showErrorTip to true the tooltip error message works fine (also with out validator).

Comment: Now you can see the error message on mouse over of the item right ? instead what you want to do ?

Comment: It should look like in this screenshot I found online: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/flex/videotraining/exercises/ex3_06/2011-05/figure01.jpg

Comment: OK, this would be a workaround. I already thought of that. But there is a integrated function in Form and FormItem that I can't get to run in my special case. I'm slowly running out of options so I'll maybe just do the workaround. I'm off for today and try again tomorrow. Thanks for now :-)